# How to prove that the function $f(x)$ is integrable on $[1,5]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Show that the function $\ f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is integrable on $[1, 5]$

I know the Riemann integral definition implies theorem:

> A bounded function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is integrable if and only if for each
>   $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $ \delta > 0$ such that
>   $mesh(P)$ < $ \delta $ implies $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$
>   for all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$

But I am struggling to put this theorem into actual use.

Comment: Have you reached the theorem that every continuous function on a compact interval is integrable?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No, that theorem isn't covered in this chapter.

Comment: Have you reached the theorem that every monotone function on a compact interval is integrable?

Comment: $f$ is continuous, hence uniformly continuous. Then take the mesh be that $\delta$ for each $\varepsilon$.